# How can I create an indexed dataframe after predicting values in decision tree

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm creating a decision tree algorithm

I have 4 features with 4 possible values on each ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

Y (the predicted values) can be 0 or 1 or 2

I have one function to build the tree then I use a predict function (I'm building it for the moment so I don't post the code) to predict values based on that decision tree.

Here is the prototype of my function

```
def dt_predict(x, features_label, tree):
```

where:

- `x` is the pandas DataFrame containing all the datas (4 columns of 4 possible values each)
- `features_label` are the title of each data columns
- `tree` is the trained decision tree a (kind of a linked list of node class)

`node` class:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
        self.option = ""
        self.feature = ""
        self.is_leaf_node = False
        self.is_pure_node = False
        self.max_value_item = ""
        self.max_value = 0
        self.possible_values_names = []
        self.possible_values_nodes = []
```

All of this was to give you an overall idea of the problem.
Now my problem is not how to predict this or that value but more how to keep track of the indexes.

In my predict function I'm going through all of the tree (nodes) and successively reducing `x` DataFrame I'm passing as argument. So I always have the index of each rows of datas but don't know how to create and paste on a new pandas dataFrame the y and index value.

```
def dt_predict(x, features_label, tree):
   if tree.is_leaf_node == True:
       #return new pandas dataframe with x indexes and tree.max_value_item (in this case 0 or 1 or 2)
   #loop through possible values, filter x and call dt_predict recursively
   ...
```

Please let me know if that's not clear.

**EDIT:**

to be more clearer imagine I have

```
index | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 |
 123  |  a |  c | a  |  b |
 ...
 35   |  b |  d | a  |  a |
```

I want it to be:

```
index |  Y |
 123  |  2 |
 ...
 35   |  2 |
```

Comment: If your predict function is set up to output only a prediction, then could you conceivably use `df.apply()` to apply it to all rows in your df?

Comment: @G.Anderson First thank you for your answer. Could you please show me an example also there's one thing to know I've told in the post but didn't asked for, as my prediction runs X is reduced to the number of options taken I need to merge the return into one final dataframe. Many thanks in advance

Comment: I apologize, but I don't really understand your phrasing. You mean that you are modifying the original DF as part of the model training process? Because that may not be the best option. For example, the sklearn decision tree models store a fitted decision tree based on the data as an object, then the `predict` method just takes the features as inputs, and outputs a single prediction (X in, y out)

Comment: @G.Anderson lol my turn to not understand. Let me explain. What I do is create a tree (linked list of nodes with particular logic) so if I get `a` after splitting on `x1` then I go to leaf node or another split. Not sure if sklearn does the same thing but you know that's just the way I've builded the whole thing. Looks similar as what you've described though

Comment: I'll admit, this may be a bit over my head, haha, but if you want to see how it's done in the most commonly used package, you can look at the `predict` functions defined in the source at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/tree.py. Not sure if it will be helpful or not

Comment: @G.Anderson thank you for the link. But if your comment with the 'apply' solution works please add it as answer and be sure I'll upvote and mark it as answered. Best.

Comment: Added possible answer, may or may not be what you're looking for!

Comment: @thank you I'll mark is as answered if I don't get any other answers. It doesn't really answered in the way I though but still good to know about `apply`

Comment: An upvote is good enough, if it doesn't actually answer the question then don't feel the need to accept the answer. Better to have no answer than a wrong one.

Comment: Okay thank you very much mind for a chat so I can I can show you my code?

Comment: I'm afraid I won't have dedicated time for a chat. Apologies!

Comment: @G.Anderson No problem thanks anyway you really helped me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, I'm not sure if there is enough information to go on. But, if you `dt_predict` function only outputs a single prediction based on a single row of input features, then it could be used to add a predictions column back to your original dataframe like the following:

```
def dt_predict(df_row):
    features=df_row.values
    #magic goes here to predict based on features
    return predicted_class

df['prediction']=df.apply(dt_predict, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks is this possible to create a new dataframe with apply?

Comment: No, this is meant to be used on the original training dataframe, and maintain the existing indices

Comment: and you don't see how I could keep original index and create a new dataFrame?

Comment: That is difficult to know without seeing what is happening in the background of your whole model training script, which is outside the scope for stackoverflow. If you want to create a new DF with the indices of the old one, then you could get the indices with `df.index` as you bring in the data and keep that index as a node attribute, maybe, then return that with your prediction and `pd.concat` the predictions together

Comment: If you have something that mostly works but you want to do it better, you may look into https://codereview.stackexchange.com/